# VS Code is looking for files in C:\c:\ directory which does not exist, resulting in many problems with namespaces and modules in my project

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, elmish

I have a project opened in VS Code. The project folder is on my desktop. When in VS Code, I attempt to work on a file but get many problems in the 'PROBLEMS' tab. It says the file is in C:\c:\Users\Me\Desktop, but I don't have a C:\c:\ directory which I believe is the cause for all the problems. This prevents intellisense from working correctly. How can I fix this problem?

I've tried cloning the project into different directories but the same problem arises.

I've tried looking for the C:\c:\ directory but it does not exist.

When I click on one of the problems I get, 'Unable to open 'filename.fs': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (c:\c:\Users\Me\Desktop\projectfolder\src\Client\foldername\filename.fs))'

Problems that appear are namespace or module 'Elmish' is not defined. This happens for everyt namespace and module in my project.

'Unable to open 'filename.fs': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (c:\c:\Users\Me\Desktop\projectfolder\src\Client\foldername\filename.fs))'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and a fix is on the way:

- [bug report](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/1177)
- [fix](https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete/pull/441)

In the future please submit bug reports to the extension repository directly, as we do not track stackoverflow and this site is not meant for technical support.